# python instantiating class with dictionary and printing

Tags: python, oop

1. Why the line `print(obj_1.dic['a'].print_1())` giving me output =  "`hello_from_x \n  None`" ? actually I am confused with the "`None`"
2. Is the line `'a':x()` equivalent to a = x() #instantiate ?

'

```
class x:
    def print_1(self):
        print("hello_from_x")
class y:
    def print_1(self):
        print("hello_from_y")

class z:
    dic = {'a':x(), 'b':y()}

obj_1 = z()
obj_1.dic['a'].print_1()
print(obj_1.dic['a'].print_1())
```

'

Comment: It's because `obj_1.dic['a'].print_1()`  prints"hello_from_y" and returns None.  Then your print(...) prints None (i.e. the value returned).

Comment: At the end you're calling print on a function (print_1) which returns nothing so you obtain None. The previous line gives you  "hello from_x".

Comment: uhhhh, i get it now, what about 'a':x()

Answer (score 0):

Because your `print_1()` function does not return anything so you get output as `None`

if you do this:

```
class x:
    def print_1(self):
        print("hello_from_x")
        return "**"
class y:
    def print_1(self):
        print("hello_from_y")

class z:
    dic = {'a':x(), 'b':y()}

obj_1 = z()
obj_1.dic['a'].print_1()
print(obj_1.dic['a'].print_1())
```

you will get output `**`

Answer (score 0):

Because your print_1() return None

> Why the line `print(obj_1.dic['a'].print_1())` giving me output = `"hello_from_x \n  None"` ? actually I am confused with the "None"

No it is not.

> Is the line 'a':x() equivalent to a = x() #instantiate ?

You may want it as below

```
class z:
    dic = dict(a=x(), b=y() )
```

Comment: if it is not, then what does that line mean?

Comment: it's the way to initiate a dict - there are two ways